# Rotate an image in pygame using sprites

Tags: pygame, sprite, pygame-surface

I am making a game in pygame and I wanted to rotate an image. `pygame.transform.rotate` kept increasing the images dimensions so I thought that maybe sprites could help me to rotate an image. But the problem is more complex, I want to click somewhere on the surface and I want the image to turn into that direction, so there are infinite number of rotations the object could make. Can somebody please give me a explanation on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Image changing dimensions

Surfaces in pygame can't be rotated; they all have a horizontal width and a vertical height. When you load your image pygame creates a Surface which has a horizontal width and a vertical height equal to your image. When you rotate your image 45 degrees pygame have to create a new Surface where your original image fits. The new Surface's horizontal width and vertical height has to be the images hypothenuse to be able to fit the image.

This is supposed to be. If the problem you're having is about collision detection I'd recommend you to try other forms of collision detection like circular, or keep using rectangular but minimize it's size.

### Rotate towards specific directions

You probably should use vectors to make the image turn to where you click. I usually create my own vector class, but [pygame has its own Vector classes](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2) which should be used unless you want to create your own for learning purposes. If you don't know how [add, subtract, scalar multiply](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/vectors.html), [normalize](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/programming-natural-simulations/programming-vectors/a/vector-magnitude-normalization) and [calculate angle between](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/vectors/angleBetween/) vectors you might want to read up on it, otherwise it might be a bit complicated. Anyway this is a small portion of a basic vector class:

```
import math

class Vector2D(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Vector2D(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Vector2D(self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Vector2D):
            # Vector multiplication
            return self.x * other.x + self.y * other.y
        else:
            # Scalar multiplication
            return Vector2D(self.x * other, self.y * other)

    __radd__ = __add__
    __rsub__ = __sub__
    __rmul__ = __mul__

    def length(self):
        return (self.x ** 2 + self.y ** 2) ** (1/2)

    def angle_to(self, other, radians=False):
        """Will return the angle between this vector and the other vector."""
        if self.length() == 0 or other.length() == 0:
            return 0
        if not radians:
            return (360 / (2 * math.pi)) * (math.atan2(other.y, other.x) - math.atan2(self.y, self.x))
        else:
            return math.atan2(other.y, other.x) - math.atan2(self.y, self.x)

    def normalize(self):
        if self.length() == 0:
            return Vector2D(0, 0)
        return Vector2D(self.x / self.length(), self.y / self.length())
```

Then I would do is create a class for your image with attributes **position** and **original image**. When you're rotating the image, pygame creates a new image that's rotated. By doing this your image lose some information and therefore some quality. That's why you always should rotate the original image and not a rotated copy.

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, image_path, pos=(0, 0)):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.original_image = pygame.image.load(image_path).convert()  # REMEMBER TO CONVERT!
        self.image = self.original_image  # This will reference our rotated copy.
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect()
        self.position = Vector2D(*pos)


    def update(self):
        """Updates the player's orientation."""

        # Create a vector pointing at the mouse position.
        mouse_position = Vector2D(*pygame.mouse.get_pos())

        # Create a vector pointing from the image towards the mouse position.
        relative_mouse_position = mouse_position - self.position  

        # Calculate the angle between the y_axis and the vector pointing from the image towards the mouse position.
        y_axis = Vector2D(0, -1)
        angle = -y_axis.get_angle(relative_mouse_position)  # Negating because pygame rotates counter-clockwise.

        # Create the rotated copy.
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.original, angle).convert()  # Angle is absolute value!

        # Make sure your rect represent the actual Surface.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Since the dimension probably changed you should move its center back to where it was.
        self.rect.center = self.position.x, self.position.y
```

### A short example

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

BACKGROUND_COLOR = (0, 0, 0)


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, position=(0, 0)):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.original_image = pygame.Surface((32, 32))
        pygame.draw.lines(self.original_image, (255, 255, 255), True, [(16, 0), (0, 31), (31, 31)])
        self.image = self.original_image  # This will reference our rotated copy.
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect()
        self.position = pygame.math.Vector2(*position)

    def update(self):
        """Updates the players orientation."""
        # Create a vector pointing at the mouse position.
        mouse_position = pygame.math.Vector2(*pygame.mouse.get_pos())

        # Create a vector pointing from the image towards the mouse position.
        relative_mouse_position = mouse_position - self.position

        # Calculate the angle between the y_axis and the vector pointing from the image towards the mouse position.
        y_axis = pygame.math.Vector2(0, -1)
        angle  = -y_axis.angle_to(relative_mouse_position )  # Subtracting because pygame rotates counter-clockwise.

        # Create the rotated copy.
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.original_image, angle).convert()  # Angle is absolute value!

        # Make sure your rect represent the actual Surface.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Since the dimension probably changed you should move its center back to where it was.
        self.rect.center = self.position.x, self.position.y


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((720, 480))
player = Player(position=(300, 250))

while True:
    # Handle events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit()

    # Update
    player.update()

    # Render
    screen.fill(BACKGROUND_COLOR)
    screen.blit(player.image, player.rect)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Hi, I tried out your code. It works just how I wanted it to. But, could you please explain the part where you said.                                                       def __sub__(self, other):
        return Vector2D(self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y)                                     Where did you tell the class or function what the 'other' was. I checked through the code, yet I cant see where you told pyhton what the 'other' was

Comment: It's a *'magic method'* (http://www.python-course.eu/python3_magic_methods.php). The method `__sub__(self, other)` is called when you're subtracting. If you create 2 vectors, **a** and **b**, from the Vector2D class and write `c = a - b` you're actually writing `c = a.__sub__(b)`. This is called *operator overloading* and is very helpful in making your code look better. In my example i wrote `rel_mouse_pos = mouse_pos - self.position` which is equal to `rel_mouse_pos = mouse_pos.__sub__(self.position)`. *other* was in this case `self.position`.

Comment: Hi, could yiu also tell me what the         self.original_image = pygame.Surface((32, 32)) does

Comment: Sorry for asking too many questions, but this code is very new to me.         y_axis = Vector2D(0,-1). Is there any specific reson you chose the y_axis to have the location of (0,-1).

Comment: @RishiMalhotra No problem :) `self.original_image = pygame.Surface((32, 32))` creates a Surface of width=32 and height=32. Surfaces are what is displayed on the screen. You've probably used `pygame.image.load("my_image.png")`, which creates a Surface with your image on. The reason why I didn't do so is because then I would have to send a picture to everyone who want to try the code. For your program you most likely should load in your image instead.

Comment: @RishiMalhotra As for `y_axis = Vector2D(0, -1)`. Vectors don't have locations. They have a direction and a size (that might point to a location). `(0, -1)` means that the vector is pointing 0 in x-direction and -1 in y-direction, or in other words: it's pointing up. Originally, your image is pointing up (even if you've an image of something pointing right, the actual Surface points up). So by calculating the angle between a vector pointing up and a vector pointing from your image to the mouse, we know exactly how much we need to rotate the image for it to point where the mouse is.

Comment: Thanks for answering those questions. Also, why did you write  `the pygame.sprite.Sprite` in  `class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):` It doesn't make a difference to the program when i delete that part.

Comment: @RishiMalhotra You're right it doesn't make a difference for this program but it's useful when creating bigger programs. You can store your objects in a `pygame.sprite.Group`, if you inherit `pygame.sprite.Sprite`, which have useful methods such as blitting all objects in the group to a Surface or call all objects update method. It's usually good practice, which is why I wrote it, even if it doesn't do anything for this program.

Comment: Could you also explain how    `return (360 / (2 * math.pi)) * (math.atan2(other.y, other.x) - math.atan2(self.y, self.x))` I understand that the 360/2pi is to convert radians to degrees but don't understand the rest of the code

Comment: @RishiMalhotra It was in the link, under *For 2D Vectors*. http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/vectors/angleBetween/

Comment: Ted: Excellent answer IMO. Would be more relevant for current versions of `pygame` if it used [`pygame.math.Vector2`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2).

Comment: @martineau Yes, you're correct! Edited it into the answer and example

Comment: Ted: Once again, nice work. I think having your own 2D vector class to illustrate what the one in `pygame.math` does is a very helpful for anyone learning about their use in this kind of context (pygame and computer graphics) or just more generally (mathematically).